# Pandas - merge values from several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that had its values split between several columns when I created it. I would like to merge columns 2-4 into one.

```
fish_frame:                         0       1       2         3  \
0                   735-8     NaN     NaN       NaN   
1                     NaN     NaN     NaN  LIVE WGT   
2                 GBE COD     NaN     NaN       600   
3                 GBW COD     NaN  11,189       NaN   
4                 GOM COD     NaN       0       NaN   
5                 POLLOCK     NaN     NaN     1,103   
6                   WHAKE     NaN     NaN        12   
7             GBE HADDOCK     NaN  10,730       NaN   
8             GBW HADDOCK     NaN  64,147       NaN   
9             GOM HADDOCK     NaN       0       NaN   
10                REDFISH     NaN     NaN         0   
11         WITCH FLOUNDER     NaN     370       NaN   
12                 PLAICE     NaN     NaN       622   
13     GB WINTER FLOUNDER  54,315     NaN       NaN   
14    GOM WINTER FLOUNDER     653     NaN       NaN   
15  SNEMA WINTER FLOUNDER  14,601     NaN       NaN   
16          GB YELLOWTAIL     NaN   1,663       NaN   
17       SNEMA YELLOWTAIL     NaN   1,370       NaN   
18       CCGOM YELLOWTAIL   1,812     NaN       NaN   

                            4      6        package_deal_column Package_Price  
0                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69           nan  
1                         NaN  TOTAL  Package Deal - $40,753.69           nan  
2                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
3                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
4   Package Deal - $40,753.69   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
5                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
6                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
7                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
8                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
9                         NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
10                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
11                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
12                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
13                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
14                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
15                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
16                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
17                        NaN    NaN  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None  
18                        NaN   None  Package Deal - $40,753.69          None
```

As you can see the `weight` values got split between several columns.

I followed this answer's directions ([pandas merge columns in same dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191066/pandas-merge-columns-in-same-dataframe)) and tried:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Column 2': pd.concat([fish_frame[1], fish_frame[2], fish_frame[3]])}).sort_index()
```

but that didn't succeed in merging them. I'm not sure if that is because I used the command incorrectly or because my problem is more specific.

Also, I didn't think this would solve it but I did try:

`fish_frame = fish_frame.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` but it didn't alter the df.

Any help solving this would be appreciated thanks.

What doing `fish_frame = fish_frame.set_index(0).stack()` produces:

```
fish_frame: 735-8                  package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
                       Package_Price                                nan
NaN                    3                                       LIVE WGT
                       6                                          TOTAL
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
                       Package_Price                                nan
GBE COD                3                                            600
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GBW COD                2                                         11,189
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GOM COD                2                                              0
                       4                      Package Deal - $40,753.69
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
POLLOCK                3                                          1,103
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
WHAKE                  3                                             12
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GBE HADDOCK            2                                         10,730
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GBW HADDOCK            2                                         64,147
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GOM HADDOCK            2                                              0
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
REDFISH                3                                              0
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
WITCH FLOUNDER         2                                            370
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
PLAICE                 3                                            622
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GB WINTER FLOUNDER     1                                         54,315
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GOM WINTER FLOUNDER    1                                            653
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
SNEMA WINTER FLOUNDER  1                                         14,601
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
GB YELLOWTAIL          2                                          1,663
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
SNEMA YELLOWTAIL       2                                          1,370
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
CCGOM YELLOWTAIL       1                                          1,812
                       package_deal_column    Package Deal - $40,753.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` and `stack`:

Depending on if your dtype of your columns header is integer or str:

```
df.set_index('0').stack()
```

OR

```
df.set_index(0).stack()
```

Output:

```
0                       
NaN                    3    LIVE WGT
GBE COD                3         600
GBW COD                2      11,189
GOM COD                2           0
POLLOCK                3       1,103
WHAKE                  3          12
GBE HADDOCK            2      10,730
GBW HADDOCK            2      64,147
GOM HADDOCK            2           0
REDFISH                3           0
WITCH FLOUNDER         2         370
PLAICE                 3         622
GB WINTER FLOUNDER     1      54,315
GOM WINTER FLOUNDER    1         653
SNEMA WINTER FLOUNDER  1      14,601
GB YELLOWTAIL          2       1,663
SNEMA YELLOWTAIL       2       1,370
CCGOM YELLOWTAIL       1       1,812
dtype: object
```

Going further renaming etc..

```
df.set_index('0').stack().reset_index(name='weights').drop('level_1',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                        0   weights
0                     NaN  LIVE WGT
1                 GBE COD       600
2                 GBW COD    11,189
3                 GOM COD         0
4                 POLLOCK     1,103
5                   WHAKE        12
6             GBE HADDOCK    10,730
7             GBW HADDOCK    64,147
8             GOM HADDOCK         0
9                 REDFISH         0
10         WITCH FLOUNDER       370
11                 PLAICE       622
12     GB WINTER FLOUNDER    54,315
13    GOM WINTER FLOUNDER       653
14  SNEMA WINTER FLOUNDER    14,601
15          GB YELLOWTAIL     1,663
16       SNEMA YELLOWTAIL     1,370
17       CCGOM YELLOWTAIL     1,812
```

Comment: Trying it with `('0')` produces: `KeyError: '0'` and trying it with `(0)` produces: `TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: Let remove the name paramater from reset_index.  Just reset_index().

Comment: That didn't merge them. The values are still split up between columns 2, 3, and 4

Comment: fish_frame.set_index(0),stack() didn't stack the values?

Comment: That produced a very strange output. The snippet of my dataframe in my original question isn't the entire dataframe so maybe that has an effect? I'll update my question to include the full dataframe, and what `fish_frame.set_index(0).stack()` produces

Comment: Ah yes...  it would look strange.